# My code violates the DRY principle, but unsure about how to proceed with refactoring

Tags: java, oop, refactoring, dry

I am very new to OOP, and have written some classes in Java which are used to convert a double value between different units of length, however I realized that I violated the DRY principle by having similar classes do basically the same thing.

**Question 1:** What might be a better solution in this situation for creating units of measurement?

**Question 2:** I would like to have all the conversion done in the 'lengthConverter' class, but I realize that it's split between multiple classes. Would it make sense to place the 'convertTo' method from the 'Feet' class into the 'lengthConverter' class and so on for each additional unit?

```
public class LengthConverter {

private Inches inches = new Inches();
private Feet feet = new Feet();
private Meters meters = new Meters();
private Miles miles = new Miles();
private Millimeters millimeters = new Millimeters();
private Centimeters centimeters = new Centimeters();
private Kilometers kilometers = new Kilometers();
private Yards yards = new Yards();

public LengthConverter() {
}

public double convert(String origUnit, double length, String toUnit) {
    double result = 0;
    switch (origUnit) {
        case "cm":
            centimeters.setLength(length);
            result = centimeters.convertTo(toUnit);
            break;
        case "ft":
            feet.setLength(length);
            result = feet.convertTo(toUnit);
            break;
        case "in":
            inches.setLength(length);
            result = inches.convertTo(toUnit);
            break;
        case "km":
            kilometers.setLength(length);
            result = kilometers.convertTo(toUnit);
            break;
        case "m":
            meters.setLength(length);
            result = meters.convertTo(toUnit);
            break;
        case "mi":
            miles.setLength(length);
            result = miles.convertTo(toUnit);
            break;
        case "mm":
            millimeters.setLength(length);
            result = millimeters.convertTo(toUnit);
            break;
        case "yd":
            yards.setLength(length);
            result = yards.convertTo(toUnit);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Error: incorrect input");
    }
    return result;
}

public class Feet {
final private double FOOT_TO_CM = 30.48;
final private double FOOT_TO_INCH = 12;
final private double FOOT_TO_KM = 0.000305;
final private double FOOT_TO_METER = 0.3048;
final private double FOOT_TO_MILE = 0.000189;
final private double FOOT_TO_MM = 304.8;
final private double FOOT_TO_YD = 0.333333;
final private double FOOT = 1;

private double length;

public Feet() {
}

public void setLength(double length) {
    this.length = length;
}

public double convertTo(String unit) {
    double result = 0;
    switch (unit) {
        case "in":
            result = length * FOOT_TO_INCH;
            break;
        case "m":
            result = length * FOOT_TO_METER;
            break;
        case "mi":
            result = length * FOOT_TO_MILE;
            break;
        case "mm":
            result = length * FOOT_TO_MM;
            break;
        case "cm":
            result = length * FOOT_TO_CM;
            break;
        case "km":
            result = length * FOOT_TO_KM;
            break;
        case "yd":
            result = length * FOOT_TO_YD;
            break;
        case "ft":
            result = length * FOOT;
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: Guess this fits better to [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Java enum.  Take a look at [TimeUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) (specifically [TimeUnit.convert​(long,TimeUnit)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#convert(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))) for conversion.  The source is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.java).